# angular 5: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Here's the code I'm trying to get to work (angular 5):

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'vcr',
  template: `
    <template #tpl>
      <h1>ViewContainerRef</h1>
    </template>
    <div>Some element</div>
    <div #container></div>
  `,
})
export class VcrCmp {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _vcr;
  @ViewChild('tpl') tpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.info(this.viewContainerRef);
    console.info(this._vcr);

    this._vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
```

The problem is that I've got this (`templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function`) error and don't really understand why.

This code is based on this example https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682 so I guess it should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer -  both calls produce the same error

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to angular 5 changelog:

> The compiler option enableLegacyTemplate is now disabled by default as
> the  element was deprecated since v4. Use `<ng-template>`
> instead.

So you should use `ng-template` instead of `template`:

```html
<ng-template #tpl>
   <h1>ViewContainerRef</h1>
</ng-template>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptkvld?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

or set `enableLegacyTemplate` to `true`:

```typescript
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { enableLegacyTemplate: true })
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpby9b?file=main.ts)**

But you should know that

**The option enableLegacyTemplate and the `<template>` element will both be removed in Angular v6.**

Answer (score 36):

In my case the error was due to me forgetting * (asterisk) before `ngTemplateOutlet`

Answer (score 12):

When you reference in the *ngIf, else clause can’t be any arbitrary component, but it must be a ng-template.

For eg,

> in a component where you have a source code similar to this:
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="myCondition ; else elseSection">
>     <!-- ... -->
> </div>
> <div #elseSection>
>     <!-- ... -->
> </div>
> ```
>
> The resulting source code should look like this:
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="myCondition ; else elseSection">
>     <!-- ... -->
> </div>
> <ng-template #elseSection>
>     <!-- ... -->
> </ng-template>
> ```

ref : https://techoverflow.net/2018/02/17/how-to-fix-angular-typeerror-templateref-createembeddedview-is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was using the same name for a variable in the component, and for a template in the HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the ngTemplateOutlet="templateValue" name was defined as a variable across the component, Using a unique value resolved the issue.

Comment: thanks! I was using a custom directive for @ContentChild and needed to add "read: TemplateRef", i.e. `@ContentChild(MyTemplateDirective, { read: TemplateRef })`

Answer (score 0):

Seems obvious, but I missed this.

In newer version(Angular 8+) this error is thrown if you're not passing the template when template was expected by Angular.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getTemplate(col) as template; else defaultColumn">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {'cell': rowData[col.field]}"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #defaultColumn>
  {{rowData[col.field]}}
</ng-template>
```

In above case your `getTemplate` method should return actual template or `null`, nothing else. I was returning Directive Class here. Hence the error.

Comment: can you pls help clarify this issue, my issue seem relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902629/angular-10-typeerror-in-browser-console-but-no-error-in-build

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due to me typed `[ngTemplateOutlet]` instead of  `[ngTemplateOutletContext]`

then `[ngTemplateOutlet]` appeared twice and caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to lazy load a component using `import` statement and `*ngComponentOutlet` but instead of `*ngComponentOutlet` I used `*ngTemplateOutlet`.

Once I fixed this it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, *ngIf has the issue.
Check whether getTemplate(col) is returning observable or simple boolean.
If observable, please check if it initialise properly or not.

```
{ng-container *ngIf="getTemplate(col) as template; 
else defaultColumn"> 
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template;
 context: {'cell': rowData[col.field]}"> 
<ng-template #defaultColumn> {{rowData[col.field]}}} 
</ng-template>
```