# Angular 10, TypeError in browser console, but no error in build

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular10, ng-template

No code changes done, upgraded to Angular 10, everything works except a feature. There were no build errors, but in browser console able to see below error. I guess this may be related to angular.core, rxjs, but unclear..appreciate your help.

```
 core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (core.js:10092)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.ngOnChanges (ng_template_outlet.ts:65)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:2131)
    at callHook (core.js:3042)
    at callHooks (core.js:3008)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:6179)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:6152)
```

Comment: From which version did you upgrade?

Comment: from angular 7 gradually one after another

Comment: Did you have that error under Angular 9?

Comment: i am not sure if I had the problem when working with Angular 9

Comment: @IsraGab I have updated the question with some code, and the last answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157228/angular-5-templateref-createembeddedview-is-not-a-function  seem very similar, in that context do you see any issue issue with the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause, I had a name for div same as ng-template which was causing the issue, once i renamed "sResult" of the ngtemplate, issue got resolved.

```
`<div
  class="tree results-container" #sResult >
  <ng-template #sResult let-items>
    <ul>`
```